# How to subtract seconds from given time in columns in Sqlite

Tags: sqlite

in sqlite table there are two columns named time_seconds and date_seconds now by using this columns i need to subtract seconds and get the time
ex

```
   date_seconds              time_seconds   
2017-06-26 17:36:41.0              7               
2017-06-26 17:36:41.0              18              
2017-06-26 17:36:41.0              126             
2017-06-26 17:36:41.0              1200
```

new_tim=date_seconds -  time_seconds

```
new_tim 
2017-06-26 17:36:34.0   
2017-06-26 17:36:23.0   
2017-06-26 17:34:35.0   
2017-06-26 17:16:41.0
```

Comment: Can you convert your `date_seconds` column to unix time, and then perform the arithmetic, and then convert back to datetime?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT datetime(strftime('%s', substr(date_seconds, 1, 19))-time_seconds, 'unixepoch') FROM X;
```